# Same MySQL query but different outputs - why?

Tags: mysql, or-operator

I use the same query in my book. Then, why is my output much different from that given in the book ?
The book also says "the || operator does not lead to the concatenation of alphanumeric values, but it is regarded as an OR operator to combine predicates". What does the "an OR operator to combine predicates" mean ?

- database: tennis
- table: player
- columns: playerno(pk), town, street, houseno ...etc.
- Problem:
  Get the player number and the address of each player who lives in stratford
- Query:

  ```
  select playerno, town || '' || street || '' || houseno
  from players 
  where town = 'stratford';
  ```
- Book's result:

  ```
  2   Stratford Stoney Road 43
  6   Stratford Haseltine lane 80
  ```

......etc

- My result(using the same query):

  ```
  2   1
  6   1
  7   1
  39  1
  57  1
  83  1
  100 1
  ```

Comment: Cant stack overflow retain the formatting of the text in my clipboard ?

Comment: update your answer with the output of `DESCRIBE player;`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - i don't understand what that means.

Comment: Paste the query that you wrote to create the database. `DESCRIBE` is a command that you can use in the mysql client (`mysql>`) to show the structure of a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you have to use `CONCAT()` to bring the values of the columns together in one string:

```
SELECT playerno, CONCAT(town, ' ', street, ' ', houseno)
FROM   players 
WHERE  town = 'stratford';
```

Your book is perhaps referring to the [Oracle concatenation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm) syntax which uses `||` to concat strings. MySQL, by default, treats `||` as an OR operator between two or more conditions, returning `1` if either of them evaluate to "true".

But as noted in satdev86's answer, MySQL *does* permit the use of `||` as a concatenation operator *only* if the mode `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` is manually set before you execute your query.

---

### EDIT:

In your book, it clearly states you have to set the MySQL `sql_mode` for the examples to work. It's on the page prior to your SQL example:

http://books.google.com/books?id=c5G42OHT96cC&pg=PT160&lpg=PT160&dq=%22This+specification+is+needed+for+the+following+examples.+It+applies+only+to+the+current+session.%22&source=bl&ots=6b6zeFbM-2&sig=3a54S4vbgmKbPBqVbbR8OdxLLI8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Nwz9T6fKAcfI2gWZhfDTBg&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA

Comment: but the book wants me to use the || operator to do the job.

Comment: @Master, what DBMS is your book using?

Comment: Very sorry for the late reply.
SQL for MySQL Developers: A Comprehensive Tutorial and Reference, as you already know.

Answer (score 1):

Because, As per book, if they have used a sql mode PIPES_AS_CONCAT, then your pipes will act as concatenation operator.

```
SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT';
select playerno, town || '' || street || '' || houseno
from players 
where town = 'stratford';
```

will give you the output as you see in book :)

Comment: For More reference http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/SQL-Statements/How-to-use-string-expressions-in-MySQL

Comment: Yes, it works. What is the meaning of "SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT';
" ?

Comment: It changes your traditional concat operation with pipes '||', check different sql modes from mysql dev documentation